# How to select a material or object using the cryptomate node if it is a volume

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, volumetrics, cryptomatte

I have a cube in the scene that I have assigned a volumetric material to. Why can't I select it using the cryptomate node when composing a scene? All materials and objects in the scene are displayed, except for those that contain volumetric material.
[image]

[image]
(Blender 3.6.1)

Comment: The docs say they are not supported.  My advice is to duplicate to a new layer, render an emission pass with your texture as emission input and use that as a mask in the compositor

Comment: @AllenSimpson can you show me an example please?